# how to judge if an identifier is a character in C programming language?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

How do I test to see if an identifier is a character ? I'm trying to test to see if an identifier named `code == I`, or if `code == D`, or if `code == C`.

This is what I have done so far.

```
char code;
double amount, service, balance;
double amtCheck, amtDeposit, openBalance, closeBalance;
int numCheck, numDeposit;
inp = fopen("account.txt", "r");

printf("Transaction\tDeposit\tCheck\tBalance");
printf("-----------\t-------\t-----\t-------");

while ((fscanf(inp, "%c %f", &code, &amount)) != EOF){
    if (code == I){
        openBalance = amount;
    }
    else if (code == D){
        numDeposit++;

    }
    else if (code == C){
        numCheck++;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes `'C'` for character literals.

Answer (score 3):

Place a single quotes around character literals `I, D` and `C`.

```
 if (code == 'I'){ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare `code` to `'I'`, `'D'`, and `'C'`.

```
while ((fscanf(inp, "%c %f", &code, &amount)) != EOF){
   if (code == 'I'){
       openBalance = amount;
   }
   else if (code == 'D'){
       numDeposit++;
   }
   else if (code == 'C'){
       numCheck++;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice in C, a char has to be surrounded with '', a string or char arrays have to be surrounded with "".
Without '', C,D, and I will be seen as variables.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a switch statement for this sort of thing. Still need the single quotes, of course.